# Why does JSONDecoder deserialize json String to Python Objects intuitively?

Tags: python, json

I have a root Class, `College` wich holds many `Course`classes

```
 class Course:

    def __init__(self, name, url, hidden, semester="SS16"):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.hidden = hidden
        self.semester = semester

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Course: (Name: %s, Semester: %s, url: %s, hidden: %s)' % (self.name, self.semester, self.url, str(self.hidden)))


class College:

    def __init__(self, url='http://dummy', courses=set()):
        self.url = url
        self.courses = courses

    def __str__(self):
        s = ('College: (url: %s, Courses:[' % (self.url))
        s += ', '.join(str(v) for v in self.courses)
        return s + "])"
```

Now I want to save/load my College Class to/from a JSON file. For Encoding I created a custom `JSONEncoder` class, which seems to work fine:

```
from json import JSONEncoder
from json import JSONDecoder
class CollegeEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, o):
        courses = list(map(lambda v: {'name': v.name, 'url': v.url,
                                      'hidden': v.hidden, 'semester': v.semester}, o.courses))
        return {'url': o.url, 'courses': courses}
```

For decoding I wrote a simple function:

```
def from_json(dct):
    if 'url' in dct:
        return College(dct['url'])
```

Now if I test JSON encoding/decoding like this:

```
myCollege = College()
myCollege.courses.add(Course("Course1", "url1", False))
myCollege.courses.add(Course("Course2", "url2", False))
myCollege.courses.add(Course("Course3", "url3", False))

dump = CollegeEncoder().encode(myCollege)
college = JSONDecoder(object_hook=from_json).decode(dump)
print(college)
```

At this point was expecting to get only a plain College object with just the url, but I get my whole College with all it's courses and their attributes

```
 College: (url: http://dummy, Courses:[Course: (Name: Course1, Semester: SS16,
 url: url1, hidden: False), Course: (Name: Course2, Semester: SS16, url: url2,
 hidden: False), Course: (Name: Course3, Semester: SS16, url: url3, hidden: False)])
```

But I don't understand how my 'object_hook' function knows how to deserialize the sub-classes. 
Should I keep it that way or expand custom deserialization? And how could I prevent my `from_json` function from behaving that way by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the JSON decoder; you used a *mutable default argument* in your `College.__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, url='http://dummy', courses=set()):
```

The `courses` default value is created **once**, when the function is created. You then add values to this one, essentially global set:

```
myCollege.courses.add(Course("Course1", "url1", False))
```

That set is never emptied, so when you create a new `College` instance, the set is *still there*:

```
>>> College.__init__.__defaults__
('http://dummy', {<__main__.Course object at 0x10f55cda0>, <__main__.Course object at 0x10f55cc50>, <__main__.Course object at 0x10f55ccf8>})
>>> foo = College()
>>> foo.courses
{<__main__.Course object at 0x10f55cda0>, <__main__.Course object at 0x10f55cc50>, <__main__.Course object at 0x10f55ccf8>}
>>> print(foo)
College: (url: http://dummy, Courses:[Course: (Name: Course3, Semester: SS16, url: url3, hidden: False), Course: (Name: Course1, Semester: SS16, url: url1, hidden: False), Course: (Name: Course2, Semester: SS16, url: url2, hidden: False)])
```

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument). Set `courses` to a sentinel instead, and create a new set in the `__init__` method if the default is still set to the sentinel. `None` is a good choice here:

```
class College:
    def __init__(self, url='http://dummy', courses=None):
        self.url = url
        self.courses = courses or set()
```

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful!